# pdf from Rmarkdown - landscape and aspectratio=169

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pdf-generation, knitr

I have made a PDF from an Rmarkdown file.
I wish to make the pdf in landscape mode so that it occupies the full screen.
The landscape mode works but it does not occupy the full screen. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694376/rmarkdown-beamer-169-aspect-ratio) article which recommends setting aspectratio=169. This is what I am unable to do.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Testing landscape and aspect ratio"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
classoption:
  - landscape
  - "aspectratio=169"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn} 
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---

```{r}

plot(rnorm(100))

```
````

I have tried ***only*** `classoption: landscape`. That ***does*** make it landscape but does not occupy the full screen.

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: Picture which does not cover the whole page]

Here is my session info():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so;  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

time zone: Asia/Kolkata
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.43

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1    xfun_0.39     
>
```

**Update**: My R version has changed but the output from this code is still the same.

Here is my new sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so;  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN       LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

time zone: Asia/Kolkata
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2
>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `fig.align='center'` to your code-chunk? Also, are you only going to keep your output on a display device (and not print it)? If so have you looked at `beamer` output instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answers targeted *figure* orientation/ratio, while the actual issue concerns *page* orientation/ratio. Also, concerning page orientation and size/ratio, I don't think the `aspectratio` is appropriate in this context for controlling page size because it would imply that the `beamer` (LaTeX) class is used while you're actually using the `article` (LaTeX) class (and it will not recognize the `aspectratio` argument).

In order to satisfy your request, you may use specifications of the geometry package rather than specifying options to the class, e.g. replace your current header:

```
---
title: "Testing landscape and aspect ratio"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
classoption:
  - landscape
  - "aspectratio=169"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn} 
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---
```

with this one:

```
---
title: "Testing landscape and aspect ratio"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn} 
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=1.5cm, paperwidth=24cm, paperheight=13.5cm 
---
```

The `paperwidth` and `paperheight` parameters to the `geometry:` line tell the geometry package to give pages specific dimensions / aspect ratio (the 16/9 aspect ratio is ensured by the fact that 13.5 = 9/16 * 24, or inversely that 24 = 16/9 * 13.5). Of course, you may change the exact dimensions and it will impact the relative font sizes and /  or aspect ratio. Also, you don't need the `classoption` part anymore.

Note that in order to clarify some aspects of the problem, you must know that the compilation of the RMarkdown document to a PDF file uses the LaTeX document preparation system. Several parameters in the header actually concern how LaTeX will generate the final PDF (`documentclass`, `classoption`, `header-includes`, `geometry`), geometry (and dcolumn) being LaTeX packages.

**Concerning the choice of these values:**

The `paperwidth` and `paperheight` parameters are documented in the LaTeX 'geometry' package (see for example
on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). For someone who is used to working with LaTeX, it is relatively natural to 'identify' LaTeX options in these lines even though they are not structured exactly this way in a LaTeX document (but their names are the same).

Concerning the choice for these specific numbers, it is relatively
arbitrary. The things to take into account are:

- These dimensions express the physical sizes of the pdf page (in a
  sense, what their size would be if the document was printed without
  adapting to the paper in your printer)
- If these sizes are reduced... the relative font size will increase
  because LaTeX will project the same font on a smaller virtual paper,
- And if these sizes are increased... the relative font size will
  decrease because LaTeX will project the same font on a larger
  virtual paper,
- It may also impact figure display on the page depending on how figure dimensions are controlled,
- I processed starting from 16x9cm sizes, resp. for paperwidth and
  paperheight, and estimated that the fonts were too large to my taste,
  then doubled them and felt that the fonts were too small for slides,
  then I ended up trying multiplying 16x9cm by a factor of 1.5, which
  gave me 24x13.5cm and I found it was ok.
- But one may vary these sizes arbitrary (even using smaller
  steps and ratios differing from 16/9) depending on the aims to be
  reached.
- It is also possible to specify different units (pt = points, in =
  inches...)

Comment: Dear Olivier, this works ***perfectly***. Many thanks. I have a small query : How did you come up with the paperwidth and paperheight values? I do understand that their ratios must be 16:9, but how do I get the precise values?

Comment: I added an answer relating to this specific aspect in the original response.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `out.extra='keepaspectratio=true'` chunk options. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925747/chunk-options-for-figure-size-with-knitrinclude-graphics-are-being-ignored): "% are translated to scaling factors to \textheight and \linewidth)"

````
---
title: "Testing landscape and aspect ratio"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
classoption:
  - landscape
  - "aspectratio=169"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn} 
documentclass: article
geometry: margin=1.5cm
---

```{r, out.extra='keepaspectratio=true', out.height='100%', out.width="100%"}
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It did not work for me though. I have added my session info. Are we on different versions of knitr perhaps ?

Comment: I am on knitr_1.43 and R 4.3.1

Comment: I assume it is still not working for you?

Comment: That's correct. It is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a base-R plot, you could do some of what you want more easily by controlling some `par()` settings. For example, to avoid extra space around the plot, use

```
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1)+.1)
plot(rnorm(100))
```